# Angular testing with qunit and httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, qunit

I have bee struggling with this all day.  Here is my test

```javascript
injector = angular.injector(['ngMock','ng', 'cockpit']);
var equal = QUnit.assert.equal;
test('loginService', function () {
    var app, service, scope, httpBackend;
    app = angular.module('cockpit');
    app.config(function ($provide) {
       $provide.decorator('httpBackend',
           angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
    });
    httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');

    httpBackend.when("PUT", "/login").respond({ userId: 23 });

    service = injector.get('loginService');
    service.$http = httpBackend;

    service.getUserId('easy', 'path');
    httpBackend.flush();
    equal(service.userId, 23, 'populates userId property');
});
```

Inside the getUserId method the $http service has not put method, so when I make the $http.put call, it fails.  I must be setting the test up incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not get that $httpBackend in Angular mocks is a wrapper for the $httpBackend in angular itself.  You just have to instantiate it and set it up to intercept the $http calls the way you want.  That said, I still can't get $httpBackend.flush() to work.  Testing in angular isn't quite as easy as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` and `$httpBackend` are two *different* services. `$http` uses `$httpBackend`. `$http` is the service which has the `put()` method.

So, the following line doesn't make sense:

```
service.$http = httpBackend;
```

Comment: That's my point.  How can you inject $httpbackend into a service using $http for acquiring data from the server?  In the AngularJS documentation for $httpBackend it shows a controller using $http and a test that injects $httpBackend in its place. When I try doing that I get an error that the object has no put method.  I can see that $httpBackend has no put method, so how does the example in the documentation work?